# Make history on ASP.NET C#

Tags: cookies, browser-history

I'm working in an e-commerce site. I've been working in the first step for shopping cart using the profile. But when it comes to history, I want to use cookies or session.

Is that possible working on that?

Comment: What "history" are you talking about? Browser history? User's previous purchases?

Comment: Yes, previous purchases.

Comment: I believe question should by in which sceanrario u should choose Session or Cookie. Once a purchase is complete u must be saving it in db as it completes 1 transaction (ideally should not keep it in session or cookie). So if u want to show this history to user on pages while user is navigating on different pages of ur site than save it as some model data (concrete class) and put it ur server session. if u want to keep track of previous purchases of the user and want to show it as soon as user visits ur site without login than u can save it in persistent cookies at user machine.

Comment: Can persistent cookies can save a <List> OR <Dictionary>. I was thinking on the first place to use an array.